# Is it possible to make an Ajax call and have PHP return headers?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I have a PHP script that produces a .CSV export file from a MySQL DB. The backend script formats the output and uses `header()`'s to open the pop-up window in the browser to download the .CSV. -- Tested and works fine.

I also have a web page that has a graphic button that launches an Ajax call to the server to produce the download .CSV file when you click the graphic button.

I tested the click event with a JavaScript `alert()` and it works fine.

I tested the click event with the Ajax call and nothing happens. Seems like I somehow need to direct the backend script to behave a bit differently.

Has anyone done anything similar to this before?

Thanks.

* HMTL (Excerpt) ***

```
<div id="exportButton"><img src="images/export.png" alt="Export to Microsoft Excel Graphic" /></div>
<h2>Page Title</h2>
<br clear="all" />
<div id="pageContent_wrapper">...
```

* JavaScript ***

```
    <script>
        jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and 

versions

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#exportButton').click(function() {
            //alert('button clicked');
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://mydomain.com/js/ajax/exportCSV.php"
            });
        });

    }); // end .ready()
    </script>
```

I am trying to accomplish this feature without having to send the user back to the server. I want the user to stay on the page.

Comment: If you're opening a new pop-up , why are using ajax call? (Just interested to know)

Comment: @OfirBaruch: By popup, I presume the OP means the browser's Save dialog.

Comment: @Amadan...yep, the save dialog window

Comment: @OfirBaruch .. I thought I needed to go the Ajax route so as not to take the user away from the page. I just did not know before I asked my question what I ended up learning about Save Dialog frames.

Comment: @Amadan ...  what does "OP" mean? Just curious (and maybe ignorant as well).

Comment: @Dr.DOT: Not programming-related, general Internet speak: "Original Poster", i.e. you.

Comment: @Amadan, I knew it had something to do with what you explained...I just couldn't put the right words together. Thanks for your help. Have a great weekend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a download from an AJAX call. The easiest solution is to wrap the button in an `<a>` element, and let the browser handle the download naturally. If you really need to have JS involved, change the `document.location` to point to the download PHP instead of invoking AJAX.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I don't want to go the <a> anchor tag route because I want the user to stay on the page. I am not as proficient with JavaScript/jQuery as I am with PHP. So can you assist me with what the `document.location` line of code might look like?

Comment: If it's a download, the user will stay on a page.

Comment: Ok, @Amadan. Maybe I over thought what would happen. I'll try the <a> anchor tag and post back.

Comment: @Dr.DOT: By "If it's a download", I meant you are setting headers correctly as Jasper shows.

Comment: Oh yeah....definitely over thought that one. You were right @Amadan. The <a> anchor tag behaved exactly like I wanted. You learn something new every day (if you're open to it).

Answer (score 1):

You can force the download of a file by setting the `Content-type` header to something that the browser will download by default, like an executable. Here's a quick example of a PHP script that does this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('huge_document.pdf');
```

Source: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Using this method you can link directly to the PHP script and avoid the JS calls. Note that forcing a `Content-type` of PDF will force a download in some browsers, and open the PDF Viewer Plugin in some browsers.

Comment: You can force a download (in browsers that properly handle mime types and not fake it by looking up extensions) by using `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper. My "download" was working fine as I had tested it earlier on directly from the browser address bar. I already had the proper headers. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.DOT The main reason to use `application/octet-stream` as the value for the `Content-type` header is because no browsers open executable files by default. So most browsers (all browsers even?) will force a download if you use the `application/octet-stream` header.

Comment: Not quite. `application/octet-stream` does not mean an executable - it means a stream of bytes about which no further semantic information is available. It could be a Mac executable, it could be the photo of aunt Esther, it could be a porn flick - and the server refuses to say which. Thus, browsers can't open it because they have no clue how to. Executables are often tagged as octet streams precisely because the people at the server don't want the browser to offer the user the possibility of running the file, but rather force the browser to download (by hiding that it's an executable).

Comment: @Jasper. When I put my solution together, I found a Stackoverflow post that I needed to be using `header("Content-Type: text/csv");` for my .CSV download. Are you saying it is better (even in my case) to use `application/octet-stream`? Even with "modern browsers"?

Comment: @Amadan. For a pure .CSV download, which content-type is better to be using? `text/csv` or `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: With `text/csv`, depending on the browser, several things might happen: you could be offered a download, you could be offered to launch with Excel, or (I have no clue, haven't touched Windows in ages) if Excel provides some kind of plugin or interoperation with IE, you might even end up automatically being shown the CSV as an excel sheet embedded within the web page (in which case the user will most definitely *not* stay on the page). `application/octet-stream` is *always* a download.

Comment: @Dr.DOT The `Content-type` header is just for the browser. Once the file is local, it's extension is used to determine file type. So you can force whichever header you want and it won't affect the data in the file. I wouldn't say it's better to use `octet-stream` because that's up-to the UX you want to create for your users. If you want to make sure the file is downloaded and not run by some app. or plugin, then force `application/octet-stream` but if you want the user's computer to determine what should happen, use `test/csv` (I would do this since the user will experience that they expect).